# Oracle Apex Size of left side column

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

in the theme roller there is an option to change the size of the left side column:

[image]

The maximum is 280px but I would like to increase the size in order to avoid scroll bars inside the menu of a faceted search. How can I increase the value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the CSS-section of the page:

```
.t-Body-side {
    width: 400px !important;
}
```

Comment: Some more detail here would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks, how to adjust auto sizing if the screen in small? The left side of the body disappear if I decrease size of the browser window and no scrollbar appear. Is there a way to adjust this?